# diffuse color material in python error

Tags: python, materials, scripting, objects, color

I am trying to add materials via python (which I am new to) but I can not even get copy and pasted code from [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/behreajj/d9d9f9f1ca248a6c8594222b582b8cf2/raw/ac4ffe121b8cc12e727fbf61b9177193d4d572a6/blender_03.py) to work. colorsys is imported and I'm using Blender 2.91.

```
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='Material ({0:0>2d}, {1:0>2d})'.format(k, j))
    mat.diffuse_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(normdist, 0.875, 1.0)
    current.data.materials.append(mat)
```

`ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 4 items, not 3.`

I have tried:

```
mat.diffuse_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(normdist, .5, 0.875, 1.0)
```

`TypeError: hsv_to_rgb() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

---

```
mat.diffuse_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(.5, 0.875, 1.0)
```

`ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 4 items, not 3`

---

```
mat.diffuse_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(.5, 0.875, 0.9, 1.0)
```

crashes Blender

---

```
mat.diffuse_color =  random(), random(), random()
```

`NameError: name 'random' is not defined`

nothing is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeError: hsv_to_rgb() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`
This error means the function expects 3 values, but you're giving it 4, so it throws an error.

`ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 4 items, not 3.`
This error tells you that the property expects a sequence of 4 items assigned to it, not 3. This is because `diffuse_color` holds 4 values: **R, G, B** and **A** for Alpha. However, the colorsys.hsv_to_rgb() returns only 3 values, as the function name suggests and as the console displays:

```
>>> colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(.5, 0.875, 1.0)
(0.125, 1.0, 1.0)
```

In order to have a sequence compatible with the Blender's property, you have to add the alpha value to that sequence:

```
mat.diffuse_color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(.5, 0.875, 1.0) + (1.0,)
```

notice the awkward comma in the parentheses - without it Python would confuse it with a float wrapped around in parentheses like in mathematical equations. You only need such awkward comma in single-element tuples.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Figuring out how to add the alpha value like that would have been so confusing on my own.